# CSS - inline SVG interferes with line-height?

Tags: html, css, svg, line-height

I'm struggling to understand the the following css behavior. Maybe I'm missing something important because this actually seems like a simple scenario to me. Consider the following example:

```css
.container {
  background-color: lime;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/>
  </svg>
  Text
</div>
```

Because `container` has `line-height: 20px` set, I'd expect it to be 20px high. At least this is the case if it only contains text. With the svg however it is suddenly 24px high, even though the svg is 20px high, as expected because of `height=1em`. Also the "Text" has a height of 23px, even though I'd expect it to be 20px.

Interestingly, if I set `container`'s line-height to something like 30px, it behaves as expected: `container` is now `30px` high.

Can you help me understand why `container` is not 20px high? Or is `line-height` simply not easily predictable once the container contains other elements than just plain text? Thank you!

Comment: Because the default for `vertical-align` (which applies here, because the SVG is an inline element) is `baseline`. Set it to `bottom`.

Comment: Great, thank you! That was exactly what I was missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things going on in your demo that are affecting the height of `div.container`. First, `line-height` isn't an explicit, fixed `height`: [it specifies the minimum height of line boxes within `div.container` in your case.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#line-height-property) Since `line-height` is a minimum, it can grow if something inside it causes it to grow.

That leads to the SVG: it has a default `vertical-align` of `baseline`, which aligns it to the baseline of `div.container`, and, due to its height, causes the `height` of `div.container` to grow to accommodate it. By changing `vertical-align` of the SVG to something else so it fits within your `20px` `line-height`, you can make it fit.

I've added a few different `vertical-align` props to your demo so you can see how alignment affects height. In general, `bottom` and `top` align the svg to the bottom and top of the line, respectively, which, given the SVG's `20px` height, keep it within the `line-height`. However, if you really, really need `div.container` to be `20px` height, `height` or `max-height` are probably better bets.

```css
.container {
  background-color: lime;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/>
  </svg>
  Default: vertical-align: baseline (24px)
</div>

<div class="container">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="vertical-align:middle">
      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/>
  </svg>
  Default: vertical-align: middle (~22px)
</div>

<div class="container">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="vertical-align:bottom">
      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/>
  </svg>
  Default: vertical-align: bottom (20px)
</div>

<div class="container">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="vertical-align:top">
      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/>
  </svg>
  Default: vertical-align: top (20px)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think I got it now :D

Answer (score 0):

This gets all heights to 20px using `flex`, `align-items: center;` and `line-height: 1rem;`:

```css
.container {
  background-color: lime;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/>
  </svg>
  Text
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. However in this case I'm not looking for a certain solution but for help to understand why this scenario behaves as it does.